# How to verify Tensorflow Serving is using GPUs on a GPU instance?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

While running Tensorflow Serving how to verify it uses GPUs for serving?
Configured Tensorflow to use GPUs during ./configure.

Tried monitoring nvidia-smi while running inference it shows no running process found.

Answer (score 1):

First， of course you need to configure to use cuda when ./configure

Second, you should compile tf serving using

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda tensorflow/...`

and

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --spawn_strategy=standalone //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server`

Lastly you can see the information when you serve the model if serving with GPU:

> I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965]
>   Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor:
>   1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.721 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 totalMemory:
>   7.92GiB freeMemory: 7.76GiB
>   I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1055]
>   Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

and check the nvidia-smi at the same time

> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  | Processes:                                                   ______________________________________________________GPU Memory |
>   |  GPU      _______ PID ______ Type _______ Process name  _______________________  Usage      | 
>   |======================================================================---| 
>   |    0  _________1215________G ________/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg_______________________59MiB |  |    0 _________     7341_______    C  ___ ...ing/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server __7653MiB | 
>   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

GPU is consumed a lot.

Comment: https://medium.com/@gr8Adakron/installing-tensorflow-serving-with-gpu-using-bazel-built-on-ubuntu-16-04-159a54ad89c4?source=user_profile---------2------------------ this might help as it properly install the tf-serving on gpu as use if efficiently